# Struts 2 Validation error

Tags: java, validation, struts2

While trying to add designation I want to validate designation name is not empty, I used the following code in xml file Designation-validation.xml

```
<field name="desgName">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        <message>Please enter designation name</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
```

But it is not working and it is adding an empty designation name in my db. But it shows the following line in my console

30 Mar, 2011 3:17:18 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger error
SEVERE: Validation error for desgName:Please enter designation name

Anyone can help? Thanks in advance...

Comment: It would be great if you can add code of jsp, struts.xml.

Comment: and the action class couldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Validation Rules** : `ActionName-validation.xml`.
Should be `DesignationAction-validation.xml`?
Or, make sure Action have extends **ActionSupport** or **subclass of ActionSupport**.

```
// Action
public class DesignationAction extends ActionSupport{ 
  @Getter @Setter private String desgName;
}
```

Comment: I hadn't extend ActionSupport or subclass of ActionSupport. But I couldn't understand the need of ActionSupport for validation.

Comment: @shinod It can be said **ActionSupport** is needed for validation. See the API of **[ActionSupport](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionSupport.html)** and **[ValidationAware](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ValidationAware.html)**

Answer (score 1):

As per the logs the field validation is working and since you haven't specified the 'trim' parameter, by default the string will be trimmed before length checking for zero, so the validation should be behaving as you want, it seems that it's being ignored on form submission.

Are any other field validations working? This could be due to a configuration issue. Have you used `<s:fielderror>` in your JSP?

Check here for how to set everything up in case you've missed something -

http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/validation.html

http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/validator/validators/RequiredStringValidator.html

Comment: @voidnull, No validation working for all fields in that page. Yes, I have used <s:fielderror> in jsp file.

Comment: @shinod - Have you checked if your workflow interceptor is configured properly? It is the workflow interceptor which checks for the presence of validation errors and if any are found takes the user back to the form which contained the validation errors. See here - [http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/validation.html#Validation-TurningonValidation](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/validation.html#Validation-TurningonValidation)